# How do all the planets defend themselves?

Tags: dragon-ball-super

This will make sense if you've seen the material, but I phrased it this way to avoid spoilers.

In Dragon Ball Super, power levels go off the charts.  Which is cool to watch in the fight scenes.  However, episode 27 showcases (`spoiler` *[link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e4_Q1KRpamA)*) how easy it is for someone of such a high level to cause an irreversible catastrophe.

Since we later learn that our usual heroes and villains aren't especially powerful in the grand scheme of things, and that there are numerically many more beings with such high power levels, how do all these inhabited worlds protect themselves from such powerful beings?  Having a planetary defense network is one thing, but if any one person could cause such a catastrophe, how do you defend against that?

Is this just how the story/plot works, or are do all these planets have defenses against this sort of thing?

Comment: many of these worlds or planets are not even aware of alien threats so they don't see the need for a defense mechanism, the others are just too weak to defend. even planet vegita got destroyed with all those powerful sayans, right?

Comment: Planet Vegeta being destroyed is another example of how hard it would be to defend a planet from a single person.

Comment: Related: [Did zen-ohs play with real planets?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/39342). From that question, I guess the answer is... none?

Comment: the thing is in this world, if you are strong enough, you can do whatever the hell you want and there is no one to stop you. like the Zen-Ohs

Comment: Many of them don't .  Frieza conquered many planets, and Buu destroyed a bunch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## **TL;DR: They don't.**

First, let's take a look at the individuals and groups throughout the Dragon Ball Universe that are capable of wreaking the levels of havok that you describe. I'll mostly be limiting this analysis to Universe 7 to start with.

### **1. The Gods**

The Gods, consisting of the Angels, the Kais, and the Gods of Destruction, among a few others, are a powerful group of deities that preside over the 12 Universes and maintain balance. The Gods of Destruction are mostly responsible for - you guessed it - destruction, so they cannot be expected to help defend mortals from various threats. Similarly, the Angels are merely the attendants of these gods, and do not directly take almost any actions beyond what their respective god wishes of them. This dynamic can be clearly seen when [Beerus refuses to take any action against Golden Freeza](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iLKYwHlYTmg) when he arrives on Earth, and when he does not attempt to stop Goku Black when he invades the present timeline.

On the other hand, the Kais are tasked with ensuring mortals are able to live in peace and advance themselves as much as possible. However, their approach to actually accomplishing this is quite hands off. They do not intervene in the affairs of mortals directly in the majority of cases, preferring to simply observe and allowing them to engage in as much destruction as they please. They did not make any effort whatsoever to stop Freeza and his family from dominating the universe. However, they do occasionally provide their help in cases of extreme universal peril, such as the first and second appearances of Majin Buu in Universe 7, or Zamasu's rampage in Universe 7/10 (though the Zamasu thing was sort of on them).

### 2. Namekians

Namekians, though a peaceful race, boast very powerful fighters capable of doing serious amounts of damage. Though most Namekians are not fighters, the Namekian warriors we see fight against Dodoria and Zarbon have a power level of roughly 3,000, according to the [Dragon Ball Wiki](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Power_Levels). To get an idea of how powerful that is, the same wiki lists Master Roshi's highest power level at 180 - and he was able to destroy the moon with a Kamehameha. Despite this level of power, though, they are actually the only Namekians we see besides Nail (and Piccolo) that are able to put up any level of resistance against Freeza and his soldiers. Though there may have been other warriors that were killed offscreen, we can conclude that Namekian warriors of this caliber are actually quite rare. As we saw, they were clearly not enough to defend the planet.

### 3. The Freeza Force

The Freeza Force is undoubtedly the largest organized force of powerful beings that we encounter in Universe 7, in terms of sheer numbers. Though the average Freeza goon is not **that** powerful (we see Roshi defeating many at once during Resurrection F), they are still much stronger than the average mortal. As well, the Freeza Force has quite a large array of very powerful individuals, including:

- Cui
- Zarbon
- Dodoria
- The Ginyu Force
- Shisami
- Tagoma

And of course, Freeza himself.

The Freeza Force also has control of the entire Saiyan race, who are quite powerful on average, similar to Namekians. The difference, though, is that the Saiyans are a warrior race, so everyone was encouraged to grow as strong as possible. It is hard to know the average strength of a Saiyan - I do not believe it is ever stated - but even if the average Saiyan was only a tenth as strong as Raditz, a low class warrior with a power level of 1500, they would still be a very powerful force, especially with their Great Ape forms. Remember, Roshi destroyed the moon with a strength of 180. It's easy to see why Freeza destroyed them before they began to threaten him.

Finally, we have...

### 4. Earthlings

The Earthlings, otherwise known as the Z-Fighters, are the other notable group of beings in Universe 7. Assuming the farmer that encountered Raditz represents the average human, humans are not at all powerful with a power level of 5 according to [the wiki](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Power_Levels). However, they have the potential to grow quite powerful as seen with Krillin, Tien, and Yamcha (don't laugh). The Earth has also produced other extremely powerful fighters, including Goku and Gohan, the Androids, and Cell, all of whom are astronomically powerful in the grand scheme of things. Consider that before Goku came around, there was no one powerful enough to challenge Freeza - even in his first form.

### Get to the point already!

All this is to say that powerful, planet destroying beings are actually not that common. In the scale of the Universe, the fact that there are only around 4 major groups that deal with beings in that power scale tell us that this isn't something that most planets are likely to encounter on a regular basis. Indeed, the Galactic Patrol from Dragon Ball Super seems to be somewhat influential, with their Galactic King being invited to the Universe 7/Universe 6 tournament between the Gods of Destruction, and yet we know that one of their elite patrolmen, Jaco, is not powerful at all. Bulma threatened to [send Vegeta to destroy Galactic Control headquarters](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KtTYYMK_CK8), and Jaco was scared silly. The Galactic Patrol has no way to fight him.

Knowing this, it is safe to assume that for the most part, planets do not have any reliable way to defend themselves against extraordinarily powerful individuals. Planet Vegeta was wiped out by Freeza single-handedly, and the same would have happened to Namek if the Z-Fighters hadn't intervened.

Note that this does not necessarily apply to other Universes, though - Universe 11 has the Pride Troopers, who seem to patrol to random planets and [stop threats](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cYEhCudb1aE), and Universe 6 has the Saiyans, who [hire themselves out](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hV9O_28Sq3g) to protect other planets.

## Update: The Galactic Patrol

As of the Dragon Ball Super Manga chapter 43, we can see that the Galactic Patrol has been around Universe 7 for at least 10 million years. As well, Merus, a member of the Galactic Patrol, was able to get the drop on Vegeta and stun him with a stun gun, by Vegeta's own admission. It may be that the Galactic Patrol does indeed have skilled members capable of holding their own against powerful beings, and Jaco is merely an incompetent outlier.

## The Other Universes

To address the comments, I'll talk about how the other Universes deal with such threats in more detail, since the above answer pertains mostly to Universe 7.

**Universe 1:**

Not much is known about them, besides the fact that they have a very high mortal level, making them exempt from the Tournament of Power. It's hard to make any judgments here.

**Universe 2:**

We don't get to see their universe much, but it is seen in episode 91 that an audition is being held to determine who will fight in the Tournament of Power. This could mean that strong fighters are common here. As well, the fact that the Tournament is public knowledge (it is later seen being broadcast to all of Universe 2) could potentially imply that the gods of Universe 2 interact with mortals more regularly, which could extend to defense (though this is speculation).

**Universe 3:**

Universe 3 has [Katopesla](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Katopesla) among their roster, who is apparently some sort of policeman in his Universe. Though he is likely the strongest of them, since he was selected for the Tournament, there may be more who, while weaker, have a high power level, and help defend the Universe from threats.

**Universe 4:**

Though they fight in the Tournament of Power, we don't know hardly anything about them. Considering how much of a jerk Quitela is, though, I doubt he takes the time to defend any planets (especially since he's a God of Destruction...).

**Universe 5:**

Like Universe 1, they didn't even enter the Tournament of Power, and we don't know much about their Universe at all.

**Universe 6:**

As briefly stated above, Universe 6 has the Saiyans, who hire themselves out to protect other planets. Frost also claimed to do a similar thing initially, though it was eventually revealed he was instigating the conflicts that he was resolving. Still, it shows there is at least some level of a formal defense organization in this Universe. It's unknown what the Namekians of this Universe do with their time (though they were all willing to fuse into [Saonel](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Saonel) and [Pirina](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Pirina) to ensure their survival).

**Universe 7:**

See my old answer.

**Universe 8:**

Same story as Universes 1 and 5: we don't know anything about this Universe.

**Universe 9:**

We do get a bit of insight into Universe 9. We know that this universe is extremely difficult to survive in, since it was described by the Trio De Dangers as a "garbage dump" (according to the [wiki](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Universe_9)). Considering the utter chaos the universe seems to be in when Sidra [destroys a city](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WHfJh__qY48), we can probably assume there isn't much in the way of defense for most planets.

**Universe 10:**

Though there are several strong fighters in this Universe, like Obuni, we never get to see if there is any form of a defense force. It certainly won't come from the gods, considering Gowasu's policy of leaving mortals to develop, similar to Shin (this was also one of the reasons Zamasu betrayed Gowasu).

**Universe 11:**

As mentioned briefly in my old answer, Universe 11 has the Pride troopers, who actively patrol the Universe and destroy threats, as seen [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cYEhCudb1aE).

**Universe 12:**

Like Universes 1, 5, and 8, this Universe was exempt from the Tournament of Power, so we didn't learn much about them.

### Summary

Overall, while it seems that some Universes have some level of defense for all planets, many of them do not, and would have to rely on powerful altruistic individuals to protect them from evil or destructive forces.

Comment: Why the downvotes? Any feedback for how I can improve this answer?

Comment: Prolly someone being extra pedantic with a side of OCD.  Your answer refers exclusively to Universe 7 with no mention or comparison of the other Universes, while I ask the question in a more general sense to include the other Universes.

Comment: Can you draw more correlation from your data/hypothesis in Universe 7 and extrapolate how that might be similar to the other Universes?  Also, for Earth specifically, Earthlings don't know about aliens.  In other Universes, people are familiar with how things actually work, including aliens and the kami's

Comment: Fair enough. I'll take another crack at it with that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Well the answer to your question would be "Mr. Satan", with regard to the earth in Universe 7. Ever since the Cell arc where Mr. Satan took credit for Gohan's win, he has been considered as the savior of the earth. Hence the population are under the impression that his power is rivalled by none and he is strong enough to defeat any beings that would put the risk of the planet or life of mankind at stake

The main story of Dragon Ball revolves around the Earth in Universe 7 and since the Z fighters happen to live there, they more or less keep the earth safe. With regard to universe 11, we, later on, learn about a group of fighters called the "Pride Troopers" who basically do what you described. With regard to the other universes, we don't know whether they actually have any organizations or any form of defense against these beings

You have to also remember that there is Jaco//the Galactic patrol which tends to keep an eye on this regard, however they obviously do not have the strength to fight against beings at that level. Also, every universe as a Supreme Kai who happens to have multiple Kai's under him.(Like King Kai under Shin). They usually would watch over these planets and keep a check with regard to this.

Comment: Kai's don't have that much power to fight against powerful beeing like freeza Goku states that supreme Kai of univese 10 (zamasu) is the strongest and Goku is ssj1 while fighting

Comment: Firstly, it was stated in the Buu saga that every single Kai living in Supreme Kai's world was strong enough to destroy namek saga Freiza(Which even Goku struggled to do until he turned SSJ). Also, Goku turned SSJ2 against Zamasu and not SSJ1. So I suggest you look up your facts first.

Answer (score -1):

Most of the planets don't sufficiently defend themselves.  Many end up enslaved or destroyed.

In the first or second episode of Z, It was revealed that the Sayans went around conquering planets, often killing off all the inhabitants.

Frieza had a large empire of hundreds of planets before he was defeated by Goku.